# Horizonatally align Crosstab on page

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

My product catalog displays a list of available stock with images. I use a crosstab to display the stock with sizes at the bottom of the page and an image of the product in middle.

How can I align the crosstab in the horizontal center of the page? Crosstab items can grow according to sizes available in stock.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something Crystal supports. Your best option is to approximate the position you want formulaically. Click the `x+2` button when setting the crosstab's Size and Position:

[image]

You can write a formula here that will alter the X position of the crosstab based on whatever fomula you like. I'd recommend setting up a Running Total to count the number of "sizes available in stock" (and if you want to get really precise, you can calculate a rough guess of the length of each column name based on the number of chars in the string.)

Otherwise there's really not a good way to handle this in Crystal.